# In Vue with TypeScript, SubmitEvent handler is not assignable

Tags: typescript, forms, vue.js

I'm using Vue with TypeScript and I want to assign a submit handler function to my form's submit event.  Here's my component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    function handleSubmit(e: SubmitEvent) {
        console.log(`Submitted: ${e.defaultPrevented}`);
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h4>Create new</h4>
        <div>
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, Volar in VS Code gives me an error for `submit.prevent` saying:

> Type '(e: SubmitEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(payload: Event) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'e' and 'payload' are incompatible.ts(2322)

What am I supposed to do here?  The function does indeed receive a `SubmitEvent` yet TS says that the type is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubmitEvent` interface is based on `Event` interface. Thus, you can cast Event to SubmitEvent;

```js
function handleSubmit(e: Event) {
    const event = e as SubmitEvent;
    console.log(`Submitted: ${event.defaultPrevented}`);
}
```

Comment: Heh, I didn't know TS let you cast to a more specific type just because it extends another.  Surely that's unsound.  Ah well, that explains why I'll always prefer C#.  Still, why does Vue define an `onSubmit` event as returning an `Event` object in the first place, instead of a `SubmitEvent`?